# Moving TFS database

Tags: tfs

Our TFS database was installed on the c: drive, but should have been installed on the f: drive (1 Tb drive).  To move this do we simply need to unmount the databases, move MDF and LDF files to the new drive, and remount the databases?

Are there any gotchas that will bite us if we do the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you properly turn off the tfs services on all your TFS Application Tiers before detaching the databases using

> `tfsservicecontrol quiesce`

From the Applicatier Tier server console.

Then after moving everything make sure you turn them back on using

> `tfsservicecontrol unquiesce`

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff470382.aspx

Comment: On all Application Tier servers

Comment: Thanks guys, made that explicit and referenced MSDN guide